# Can a computer connected to another computer in the network join the network?

Tags: networking, windows-networking

This is difficult to explain only by words. See the picture below. The goal is to make PC3 part of the network where PC1 and PC2 belong. Of course, assume that PC2 is on when PC3 is on. The operating systems are Windows.

The reason why I do not connect PC3 to the router is that there is a wall, so it will be difficult to connect PC3 to the router directly. PC2 is directly connected to the router, but it was difficult to do so, so I do not want to do it again for PC3.

[image]

Comment: Why not buy a switch and connect the router cable to the switch and then plug both PCs into the switch? This will easily solve the problem and you won't need PC2 on just because you want to use PC3.

Comment: PC2 is the main PC and PC3 is a back up PC so most of the time, I would not use PC3. Some of the reviews on Amazon said using a switch decreased network performance, and I did not want the network speed of PC2 to decrease, so I thought of this option.

Comment: The speed will remain the same if you add a switch. There will be slight latency added with a switch but it's so small there is no need to even bring it up. There will be measureable delay and speed difference though if you go from PC2 to PC3 instead of through a switch. That being said, if people complained about speed issues with a switch then it might be a issue with that specific switch. Stick with a name brand and you should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of configuring PC2 to pass traffic from PC3, your best option is to use a network switch. A switch will allow both PCs to connect to it and PC2 won't have to be on just because you want to use PC3. All you need to do is plug the router cable and both PC cables to it and you're done. And since most switches have 4 or more ports, you'll have a spare for down the road.

Comment: If configuring PC2 is that difficult, then I guess I will use a switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a static route in your router to direct traffic to the PC3 using PC2 as the gateway.